# C# + PHP - Calling method and returning data

Tags: c#, php

I can't seem to get the right data returned. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$u = $_GET['u'];
$p = $_GET['p'];

require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}

//Prevent the user visiting the logged in page if he/she is already logged in
if(isUserLoggedIn()) { header("Location: account.php"); die(); }

//Forms posted
if(!empty($_POST))
{
$errors = array();
$username = sanitize(trim($_POST[$u]));
$password = trim($_POST[$p]);

//Perform some validation
//Feel free to edit / change as required
if($username == "")
{
    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_SPECIFY_USERNAME");
}
if($password == "")
{
    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_SPECIFY_PASSWORD");
}

if(count($errors) == 0)
{
    //A security note here, never tell the user which credential was incorrect
    if(!usernameExists($username))
    {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USER_OR_PASS_INVALID");
    }
    else
    {
        $userdetails = fetchUserDetails($username);
        //See if the user's account is activated
        if($userdetails["active"]==0)
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_INACTIVE");
        }
        else
        {
            //Hash the password and use the salt from the database to compare the password.
            $entered_pass = generateHash($password,$userdetails["password"]);

            if($entered_pass != $userdetails["password"])
            {
                //Again, we know the password is at fault here, but lets not give away the combination incase of someone bruteforcing
                $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USER_OR_PASS_INVALID");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //Passwords match! we're good to go'
                return 1;
                //Update last sign in
                $loggedInUser->updateLastSignIn();
                $_SESSION["userCakeUser"] = $loggedInUser;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

It always returns incorrect details (0). Here is the C# code:

```
public static string Login(string user, string pass)
    {
        WebClient c = new WebClient();

        string a = c.DownloadString("http://www.zilentsoftware.com/static/user/account/zlogin.php?u=" + user + "&p=" + pass);

        return a;
    }
```

It wont return the correct value - even when all the info is correct. I have no idea how to fix this! I want to check the username and their password against the database. This is the same method as the website login but it's not working. I've looked on the UserCake documentation and there is nothing!

Comment: The only question you asked is 'any ideas for this' on the bottom of your code snippets. You'll need to be more clear than that. What exactly is your problem and what exactly is your question?

Comment: I´m no PHP-guru, but maybe look at your last else-statement: you return with code 1 and afterwards you want to set the value of a session-cookie. I guess these two lines are never executed which will lead to the cookie not being set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this line

```
$entered_pass = generateHash($password,$userdetails["password"]);
```

does what you want?
You generate a hash with the password the user entered and the saved password in your db.

After this you compare this generated hash with the password you used before to hash the entered password. Which will always be false (except you hit a collision)

```
if($entered_pass != $userdetails["password"])
```

I think you maybe meant

```
$entered_pass = generateHash($password,$userdetails["hash"]);
```

or something similar because your comments say you use the hash to generate the password hash.

I don't know how you generateHash method works so I can't say for sure if this is the reason your application does not work as intended. You may also look at the statements after return because I am not sure if they will be executed